# Taylor expansion of Fourier series coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, quantum-mechanics

I am trying to obtain a result in condensed matter physics, and got stuck in math. Basically I want to Taylor expand the coefficients of a Fourier series expansion of a function $f$:
$$f(x)=\sum_n c_n e^{inx}$$
with
$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-inx} dx.$$
Then I try to substitute $f(x)=\sum_k \frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(0) x^k$ in the integral of $c_n$. I get
$$c_n=\sum_k \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(0)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^k e^{-inx} dx.$$

Now, if I could integrate that, I would be able to advance. Have I done something wrong in the derivation so far? If I have not, how can I obtain the result of that integral?

**Edit:** A more complete statement of the problem follows. I have the operator A(p,r) which is periodic:
$$A(p,r+T)=A(p,r)$$
And can be written as:
$$A(p,r)=\sum_G A_G(p)e^{iG.r}$$

I also have a function:

$$\Psi_{n,k} (r) = e^{i k.r} u_{n,k}(r)$$

Where $u_{n,k}$ is periodic with same period T and can be expanded in a Fourier series:
$$u_{n,k}(r)=\sum_G Y_{n,k,G} e^{i G.r}$$

According to the textbook I can prove, by Taylor expanding the coefficients $A_G(p)$ that the action of the operator A acting on $\Psi$ can be written as:
$$A(p,r)\Psi_{n,k}(r)=e^{i k.r}U_{n,k}(r)$$

Where $U_{n,k}$ is a linear combination of the $u_{n,k}$.

*(Please let me know if this is not the correct way to format this)*

Comment: This does not work as the integrals do not converge. Also, typically the wave functions are not regular enough that we can get a Taylor expansion. It would be helpful if you could include what you actually want to show.

Comment: Essentially you take a function which decays reasonably well at infinity (as it should be a wave function) and then you try to approximate it by polynomials. However, polynomials never decay at infinity (unless it is the zero polynomial). So, you can already see from this perspective that your approach is doomed to fail.

Comment: You should show us what is your $f$ and why you'd like to look at its Taylor series because as it is your question is confusing. For example you start with a Fourier series then you seem to look at a Fourier transform.

Comment: In the formula for $c_n$ we tipically integrate on $(-\pi,\pi)$ and not on $\mathbb R$. Also it is better to write $f^{(k)}(0)$ and not $d/dx^k f(0)$.